# In the MetalImageRecognition sample code provided by Apple, how is the batch normalization performed on the weights and biases parameters?

Tags: neural-network, ios10, conv-neural-network, metal

The README provides the following comment:

```
/* 
The weights for this particular network were batch normalized but for inference we may use : 

w =  gamma  / √(s + 0.001), b = ß - ( A * m ) 

s: variance 
m: mean 
gamma : gamma 
ß: beta 

w: weights of a feature channel 
b: bias of a feature channel 

for every feature channel separately to get the corresponding weights and  bias 
*/
```

I have been able to export all of the trained parameters from a retrained Inception model to binary, using TensorFlow. For example, for the first convolution node, these are the available binary files:

> conv0/BatchNorm/beta
>   conv0/BatchNorm/beta/ExponentialMovingAverage
>   conv0/BatchNorm/beta/RMSProp
>   conv0/BatchNorm/beta/RMSProp_1
>   conv0/BatchNorm/moving_mean
>   conv0/BatchNorm/moving_mean/ExponentialMovingAverage
>   conv0/BatchNorm/moving_variance
>   conv0/BatchNorm/moving_variance/ExponentialMovingAverage
>   conv0/weights
>   conv0/weights/ExponentialMovingAverage
>   conv0/weights/Regularizer/L2Loss/value/avg
>   conv0/weights/RMSProp
>   conv0/weights/RMSProp_1

Are these files transformed or recomputed to get the corresponding **conv.dat** file somehow, or is there a function in TensorFlow to export each node with batch normalization?

Any additional direction would be extremely helpful, as there are few resources to connect the dots here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I created a repo that converts Inception v3 batch-normalized weights to the de-normalized weights needed by MPSCNNConvolution.

https://github.com/kakugawa/MetalCNNWeights

In the paper 'Batch Normalization: Accelerating Deep Network Training by Reducing Internal Covariate Shift' by Sergey Ioffe and Christian Szegedy (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167v3.pdf), we can use Algorithm 2, Output, Step 11 to derive:

```
[Weight = \frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{Var[x]+0.001}} * Weight_{BN}](http://mathurl.com/z7snq3z.png)
[Bias = \beta - (\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{Var[x]+0.001}}) * E[x]](http://mathurl.com/zo4shhf.png)
```

Note: I need 10 reputation points before I can post images or 2 links.